# If I wanted to create a fixed set of characters, which of these declarations is correct?

Tags: c++

If I wanted to create a fixed set of characters, which of these declarations is correct? Are they different? If so, how?

```
const std::set<char> S;
```

versus

```
std::set<const char> S;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first one:

```
const std::set<char> S;
```

`const` refers to `S`, i.e. the `set` is `const`.
In the second:

```
std::set<const char> S;
```

the `const` refers to `char`, i.e. the `char` elements are `const`.

You're probably looking for the first declaration.  Note: becuase it's `const` you must initialise `S` at it's instantiation.

Comment: FWIW: the members of an `std::set` are const anyway, even if you declare it `<char>`.